# Inverse of Flatten in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What's the inverse of f[x_]:=Flatten[x] where x is Array with dimensions dims?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no built-in function, but it's pretty easy with a combination of [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html?q=Fold&lang=en) and [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html?q=Partition&lang=en):

```
In[47]:= x1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 4, 5}];

In[48]:= dims = Dimensions[x1]

Out[48]= {3, 4, 5}

In[49]:= x2 = Fold[Partition, Flatten[x1], Most[Reverse[dims]]];

In[50]:= x1 == x2

Out[50]= True
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `Partition[]` or one of its relatives.