# Converting 1D list to 3D list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have function which converts a 1D list to a 3D list, but at the same time when 2nd and 3rd dimension indices are equal it places zeroes instead of values from the input list:

```
n = 4

input = Table[RandomInteger[5], {i, 1, 48}]

convert[l_] := Table[If[i == j, 0, l[[index++]]], {s, 1, 4}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]

output = convert[input]
```

I'd like to get rid of the Increment[] (++) function.

Comment: How is `n` defined in the `Table` iterators?

Comment: @rcollyer I've added n assignment to my question

Comment: Also look at the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/q/3807976/421225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work:

```
convert[l_] := Insert[Partition[Partition[l, 3], 4], 0, 
                      Flatten[Table[{j, i, i}, {j, 4}, {i, 4}], 1]]
```

Perhaps someone more savvy may help to get rid of the *Partition[Partition* nasty construction.

HTH!

Comment: Sadly, there is not yet a replacement for using nested `Partition` calls (see ["Inverse of Flatten in Mathematica"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807976/inverse-of-flatten-in-mathematica/3808284) for a generic solution, at least)

Comment: Also, I suggest `ReplacePart[..., {_, i_, i_}->0]` instead of `Insert`, you don't need to build a list of partspecs but can use a simple pattern instead.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the pointer.Shame on me, I have had voted up your answer ... and forgot it. Regarding the ReplacePart[] suggestion, I don't find an elegant way to use it. Please feel free to edit my answer or post another one (the Insert is really clumsy)

Comment: @belisarius, Literally, just `ReplacePart[Partition[Partition[..],..], {_,i_,i_}->0]` will do the trick. The pattern matches all elements whose part specification have the second and third elements equal, but without having to specify actual partspec values.

Comment: Ohhh, nevermind on `ReplacePart`, I mis-parsed what the OP was doing. Mea culpa, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Michael Deleted. No corpse, no murder :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative (ab)using [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html), but it does not eliminate the need for an index variable and increment:

```
convert[l_] := Module[{q=1},
  Normal[SparseArray[{{_,i_,i_} -> 0, {i_,j_,k_} :> l[[q++]]}, {3, 4, 4}]]
]
```